# Odd definition of derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives

I saw a bit different definition of derivative fiven by $f(x+\epsilon) = f(x)+f'(x)\epsilon + {\cal O}(\epsilon^2)$, where the ${\cal O}(\epsilon^2)$ stands for any function $g$ which satisfies that for all $x$ sufficiently large exists $c>0$ in which we have $g(x)\leq c\epsilon^2$. The defition I know is given by $r(\epsilon)$ instead of ${\cal O}(\epsilon^2)$, and satisfies $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} r(\epsilon)/\epsilon = 0$. Could someone please clarify the other defition please.

Comment: Vaguely in both cases it states that the error of the output is vanishingly small compared to the error of the input. Landau notation avoids using limit notation so it's a little easier to typeset. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @CyclotomicField but why $O(\epsilon^2)$? It shouldn't be $O(\epsilon)$?

Comment: The problem with $O(\epsilon)$ is that sometimes you end up with $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} r(\epsilon)/\epsilon= 1$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField but you also have functions that are both $O(\epsilon^2)$ and $O(\epsilon)$

Comment: $\epsilon$ is $O(\epsilon)$ and I think you can see why $\epsilon / \epsilon \neq 0$. Think of $r(\epsilon)/\epsilon$ in the case when it's an indeterminant form like $0/0$ and by requiring it to be $O(\epsilon^2)$ we avoid this case.

Comment: @piero You mean $o(\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general definition is with lower case $o(\epsilon)$ as remainder term, which is defined as the class of functions behaving like $r$. $O(\epsilon^2)$ works almost everywhere for most functions that one practically encounters, but there are examples that fall in-between.